# Parsing a lisp file with Python

Tags: python, parsing

I have the following lisp file, which is from the [UCI machine learning database](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Bach+Chorales).  I would like to convert it into a flat text file using python. A typical line looks like this:

```
(1 ((st 8) (pitch 67) (dur 4) (keysig 1) (timesig 12) (fermata 0))((st 12) (pitch 67) (dur 8) (keysig 1) (timesig 12) (fermata 0)))
```

I would like to parse this into a text file like:

```
time pitch duration keysig timesig fermata
8    67    4        1      12      0
12   67    8        1      12      0
```

Is there a python module to intelligently parse this? This is my first time seeing lisp.

Comment: Does [Parsing S-Expressions in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3182594) help?

Comment: Why not use lisp to convert it to another format?

Comment: What's the learning curve involved in learning enough lisp to do that?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14040960/989121), [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) appears to be the right tool for that:

```
inputdata = '(1 ((st 8) (pitch 67) (dur 4) (keysig 1) (timesig 12) (fermata 0))((st 12) (pitch 67) (dur 8) (keysig 1) (timesig 12) (fermata 0)))'

from pyparsing import OneOrMore, nestedExpr

data = OneOrMore(nestedExpr()).parseString(inputdata)
print data

# [['1', [['st', '8'], ['pitch', '67'], ['dur', '4'], ['keysig', '1'], ['timesig', '12'], ['fermata', '0']], [['st', '12'], ['pitch', '67'], ['dur', '8'], ['keysig', '1'], ['timesig', '12'], ['fermata', '0']]]]
```

For the completeness' sake, this is how to format the results (using [texttable](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/texttable)):

```
from texttable import Texttable

tab = Texttable()
for row in data.asList()[0][1:]:
    row = dict(row)
    tab.header(row.keys())
    tab.add_row(row.values())
print tab.draw()
```

```
+---------+--------+----+-------+-----+---------+
| timesig | keysig | st | pitch | dur | fermata |
+=========+========+====+=======+=====+=========+
| 12      | 1      | 8  | 67    | 4   | 0       |
+---------+--------+----+-------+-----+---------+
| 12      | 1      | 12 | 67    | 8   | 0       |
+---------+--------+----+-------+-----+---------+
```

To convert that data back to the lisp notation:

```
def lisp(x):
    return '(%s)' % ' '.join(lisp(y) for y in x) if isinstance(x, list) else x

d = lisp(d[0])
```

Comment: This is definitely the answer since the Op asked for "a python *module* to *intelligently* parse this"

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the data is correct and the format uniform (seems so at a first sight), and if you need just this data and don't need to solve the general problem... then why not just replacing every non-numeric with a space and then going with split?

```
import re
data = open("chorales.lisp").read().split("\n")
data = [re.sub("[^-0-9]+", " ", x) for x in data]
for L in data:
    L = map(int, L.split())
    i = 1  # first element is chorale number
    while i < len(L):
        st, pitch, dur, keysig, timesig, fermata = L[i:i+6]
        i += 6
        ... your processing goes here ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Separate it into pairs with a regular expression:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: txt = '(((st 8) (pitch 67) (dur 4) (keysig 1) (timesig 12) (fermata 0))((st 12) (pitch 67) (dur 8) (keysig 1) (timesig 12) (fermata 0)))'

In [3]: [p.split() for p in re.findall('\w+\s+\d+', txt)]
Out[3]: [['st', '8'], ['pitch', '67'], ['dur', '4'], ['keysig', '1'], ['timesig', '12'], ['fermata', '0'], ['st', '12'], ['pitch', '67'], ['dur', '8'], ['keysig', '1'], ['timesig', '12'], ['fermata', '0']]
```

Then make it into a dictionary:

```
dct = {}
for p in data:
    if not p[0] in dct.keys():
        dct[p[0]] = [p[1]]
    else:
        dct[p[0]].append(p[1])
```

The result:

```
In [10]: dct
Out[10]: {'timesig': ['12', '12'], 'keysig': ['1', '1'], 'st': ['8', '12'], 'pitch': ['67', '67'], 'dur': ['4', '8'], 'fermata': ['0', '0']}
```

Printing:

```
print 'time pitch duration keysig timesig fermata'
for t in range(len(dct['st'])):
    print dct['st'][t], dct['pitch'][t], dct['dur'][t], 
    print dct['keysig'][t], dct['timesig'][t], dct['fermata'][t]
```

Proper formatting is left as an exercise for the reader...

Answer (score 0):

cSince the data is already in Lisp, use lisp itself to manipulate the data into a well-known format like CSV or TSV:

```lisp
    (let ((input '(1 ((ST 8) (PITCH 67) (DUR 4) (KEYSIG 1) (TIMESIG 12) (FERMATA 0))
                    ((ST 12) (PITCH 67) (DUR 8) (KEYSIG 1) (TIMESIG 12) (FERMATA 0)))))
               (let*
                   ((headers (mapcar #'first (cadr input)))
                    (rows (cdr input))
                    (row-data (mapcar (lambda (row) (mapcar #'second row)) rows))
                    (csv (cons headers row-data)))
                 (format t "~{~{~A~^,~}~^~%~}" csv)))
```

```
ST,PITCH,DUR,KEYSIG,TIMESIG,FERMATA
8,67,4,1,12,0
12,67,8,1,12,0
```