# converting nested parenthesis tree to nested list

Tags: python

I have got a tree structure file,where parenthesis are used to represent the tree. Here is the code toconvert the same to a python nested list

```
def foo(s):
    def foo_helper(level=0):
        try:
            token = next(tokens)
        except StopIteration:
            if level != 0:
                raise Exception('missing closing paren')
            else:
                return []
        if token == ')':
            if level == 0:
                raise Exception('missing opening paren')
            else:
                return []
        elif token == '(':
            return [foo_helper(level+1)] + foo_helper(level)
        else:
            return [token] + foo_helper(level)
    tokens = iter(s)
    return foo_helper()
```

as given by
[how to parse a strign and return nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140850/how-to-parse-a-string-and-return-a-nested-array).

Here it works fine, when the characters are 1 in length. for words or sentences, the same doesnt properly work.
My sample of tree is:

```
( Satellite (span 69 74) (rel2par Elaboration)
        ( Nucleus (span 69 72) (rel2par span)
          ( Nucleus (span 69 70) (rel2par span)
            ( Nucleus (leaf 69) (rel2par span) (text _!MERRILL LYNCH READY ASSETS TRUST :_!) )
            ( Satellite (leaf 70) (rel2par Elaboration) (text _!8.65 % ._!) )
          )
          ( Satellite (span 71 72) (rel2par Elaboration)
            ( Nucleus (leaf 71) (rel2par span) (text _!Annualized average rate of return_!) )
            ( Satellite (leaf 72) (rel2par Temporal) (text _!after expenses for the past 30 days ;_!) )
          )
        )
        ( Satellite (span 73 74) (rel2par Elaboration)
          ( Nucleus (leaf 73) (rel2par span) (text _!not a forecast_!) )
          ( Satellite (leaf 74) (rel2par Elaboration) (text _!of future returns ._!) )
        )
      )
```

here, the output need to be 
`['satellite',['span','69','74'].........]` but with the given function what I get is `['s','a','t'...............['s','p','a','n','7','3']..............]`

How can this be modified?

Comment: Have a look on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058985/parsing-a-lisp-file-with-python

Comment: Just a quick question unrealted to the OPs question: How does `foo_helper` know `tokens`? I would've thought that a `NameError` would've been raised, since `tokens` is defined below the definition of `foo_helper`.

Comment: @SteinarLima Look at my answer which is formatted a bit better. It's an inner function and it's not called till the last line of `foo` basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed you wanted to denote strings-with-whitespace using `_!`. I then split the expression using regular expressions:

```
from re import compile
resexp = compile(r'([()]|_!)')
…
  tokens = iter(resexp.split(s))
…
```

My result was (using pprint with depth=4)

```
$ python lispparse.py  | head
['\n',
 [' Satellite ',
  ['span 69 74'],
  ' ',
  ['rel2par Elaboration'],
  '\n        ',
  [' Nucleus ',
   ['span 69 72'],
   ' ',
   ['rel2par span'],
```

I refined it a little bit further with:

```
tokens = iter(filter(None, (i.strip() for i in resexp.split(s))))
```

and got:

```
$ python lispparse.py  
[['Satellite',
  ['span 69 74'],
  ['rel2par Elaboration'],
  ['Nucleus',
   ['span 69 72'],
   ['rel2par span'],
   ['Nucleus', [...], [...], [...], [...]],
   ['Satellite', [...], [...], [...], [...]]],
  ['Satellite',
   ['span 73 74'],
   ['rel2par Elaboration'],
   ['Nucleus', [...], [...], [...]],
   ['Satellite', [...], [...], [...]]]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are intended to call this function not on the string itself, but over a list of tokens, i.e. the string `split`:

```
def parse(s):
    def parse_helper(level=0):
        try:
            token = next(tokens)
        except StopIteration:
            if level:
                raise Exception('Missing close paren')
            else:
                return []
        if token == ')':
            if not level:
                raise Exception('Missing open paren')
            else:
                return []
        elif token == '(':
            return [parse_helper(level+1)] + parse_helper(level)
        else:
            return [token] + parse_helper(level)
    tokens = iter(s)
    return parse_helper()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('tree.thing', 'r') as treefile:
        tree = treefile.read()

    print(parse(tree.split()))
```

Where `treefile` contains the data structure you posted, I get this output:

```
[['Satellite', '(span', '69', '74)', '(rel2par', 'Elaboration)', ['Nucleus', '(span', '69', '72)', '(rel2par', 'span)', ['Nucleus', '(span', '69', '70)', '(rel2par', 'span)', ['Nucleus', '(leaf', '69)', '(rel2par', 'span)', '(text', '_!MERRILL', 'LYNCH', 'READY', 'ASSETS', 'TRUST', ':_!)'], ['Satellite', '(leaf', '70)', '(rel2par', 'Elaboration)', '(text', '_!8.65', '%', '._!)']], ['Satellite', '(span', '71', '72)', '(rel2par', 'Elaboration)', ['Nucleus', '(leaf', '71)', '(rel2par', 'span)', '(text', '_!Annualized', 'average', 'rate', 'of', 'return_!)'], ['Satellite', '(leaf', '72)', '(rel2par', 'Temporal)', '(text', '_!after', 'expenses', 'for', 'the', 'past', '30', 'days', ';_!)']]], ['Satellite', '(span', '73', '74)', '(rel2par', 'Elaboration)', ['Nucleus', '(leaf', '73)', '(rel2par', 'span)', '(text', '_!not', 'a', 'forecast_!)'], ['Satellite', '(leaf', '74)', '(rel2par', 'Elaboration)', '(text', '_!of', 'future', 'returns', '._!)']]]]
```

Comment: Note that `parse` and `parse_helper` are just renamed from `foo` and `foo_helper` in the OP.

Comment: yes i am aware of this, but the problem is instead `'_!MERRILL', 'LYNCH', 'READY', 'ASSETS', 'TRUST',` I need to show it  as a single item element like `'_!MERRILL LYNCH READY ASSETS TRUST`

Comment: Yeah I'm working on adjusting the code. Stay tuned for an update.

Comment: Ugh, a storm is interfering with my internet connection. tl;dr this code is difficult to improve and now I can't work on it, so you should look into [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) (or use the other answer).